# How much is the limit of Promise.all?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Recently i got the following error while resolving a VERY large number of promises:

> RangeError: Too many elements passed to Promise.all

I couldn't find any information regarding limits on MDN or ECMA-262.

Comment: how may elements did you put in the array of promises?

Comment: 100.000 @loretoparisi

Comment: Let's investigate this!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Both in Chrome and Firefox I could pass an array with 500000 elements, and got no error. Specific to nodejs?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on nodejs either. 3 million: no problem. 4 million: out of memory.

Comment: Isn't it based on your own system's memory?

Comment: @RichS, if that is a reaction to my comment: yes, I merely want to show I cannot reproduce the "Too many elements" error.

Comment: Reaction to OP's question.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: So the answer it is yes and the code it is here: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-promise-gen.cc#L2187 More info in the answer below!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [V8/V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/message-template.h#L475) error code `TooManyElementsInPromiseAll` of the source code objects [Promise](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/promise.h)

```
  T(TooManyElementsInPromiseAll, "Too many elements passed to Promise.all")
```

there is this limit. For the Promise.all i.e. the C++ [PromiseAll](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-promise-gen.h#L139) we have there is a concept of `MaximumFunctionContextSlots` and `kPromiseAllResolveElementCapabilitySlot`, [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/builtins/builtins-promise.h#L30) it is the most interesting stuff from the source code:

```
// TODO(bmeurer): Move this to a proper context map in contexts.h?
  // Similar to the AwaitContext that we introduced for await closures.
  enum PromiseAllResolveElementContextSlots {
    // Remaining elements count
    kPromiseAllResolveElementRemainingSlot = Context::MIN_CONTEXT_SLOTS,

    // Promise capability from Promise.all
    kPromiseAllResolveElementCapabilitySlot,

    // Values array from Promise.all
    kPromiseAllResolveElementValuesArraySlot,

    kPromiseAllResolveElementLength
  };
```

I would expect to see a error throw like [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-promise-gen.cc#L254)

```
ThrowTypeError(context, MessageTemplate::TooManyElementsInPromiseAll);
```

[Here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-promise-gen.cc#L2187) it is the code that raise the `TooManyElementsInPromiseAll` error. Thank to Clarence that pointed me in the right direction!

```
BIND(&too_many_elements);
  {
    // If there are too many elements (currently more than 2**21-1), raise a
    // RangeError here (which is caught directly and turned into a rejection)
    // of the resulting promise. We could gracefully handle this case as well
    // and support more than this number of elements by going to a separate
    // function and pass the larger indices via a separate context, but it
    // doesn't seem likely that we need this, and it's unclear how the rest
    // of the system deals with 2**21 live Promises anyways.
    Node* const result =
        CallRuntime(Runtime::kThrowRangeError, native_context,
                    SmiConstant(MessageTemplate::kTooManyElementsInPromiseAll));
    GotoIfException(result, &close_iterator, var_exception);
    Unreachable();
  }
```

The check of this limit it is [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-promise-gen.cc#L2071)

```
// Check if we reached the limit.
    TNode<Smi> const index = var_index.value();
    GotoIf(SmiEqual(index, SmiConstant(PropertyArray::HashField::kMax)),
           &too_many_elements);
```

so the `kMax` should solve the clue!

Comment: And yet another piece to the puzzle is in: [contexts.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/contexts.h)... where we can see `NATIVE_CONTEXT_INTRINSIC_FUNCTIONS` (**heap-allocated** activation contexts), including `MIN_CONTEXT_SLOTS`, which is the base value for the `PromiseAllResolveElementContextSlots` enum

Comment: `kMax` can be any "max constant". The lowercase `k` in C++ is a naming convention used  to specify a constant.

Comment: "SMI" == "Static Memory Interface". Looking up the kMax field in the SmiConstant hashmap contains the answer. Each user will probably experience different limits based on system memory. Remove a RAM stick from your system and repeat the test.. You'll see what I mean :)

Comment: ...where `SmiConstant  = Type::NewConstant(js_heap_broker(), smi, zone);`!

Comment: Is it possible it's using a 32bit ptr, and that they are worried about the size of the promise? It might be an issue that wasn't fixed with 64bit support. 1<<21 leaves about 2k per promise which seems a bit on the high side. It looks like something to do with the way they are indexing the promises going by the comments.

Answer (score 9):

From the [V8 unit tests](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/test/mjsunit/es6/promise-all-overflow-1.js#L9-L12), we see this:

```
// Make sure we properly throw a RangeError when overflowing the maximum
// number of elements for Promise.all, which is capped at 2^21 bits right
// now, since we store the indices as identity hash on the resolve element
// closures.
const a = new Array(2 ** 21 - 1);
const p = Promise.resolve(1);
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) a[i] = p;
testAsync(assert => {
  assert.plan(1);
  Promise.all(a).then(assert.unreachable, reason => {
    assert.equals(true, reason instanceof RangeError);
  });
});
```

It looks like the maximum number of elements is capped at 2^21 (= 2097151), which is in line the practical tests that the other answers ran.

Comment: good catch! I'm still searching where the `TooManyElementsInPromiseAll` is raised, but I do not find it!

Comment: My follow-up question would be: what may be the reason for capping it at 2^21?

Answer (score 5):

I can say *what* the limit appears to be, though I can't pinpoint *why* exactly it is the way it is in the V8 source code. I wrote the following code (only run it if you're bored, it'll take a while):

```js
if (!window.chrome) {
  throw new Error('Only try this in Chromium');
}

// somewhere between 1e6 and 1e7
let testAmountStart = 5.5e6;
let changeBy = 4.5e6;
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const next = (testAmount) => {
  changeBy = Math.ceil(changeBy / 2);
  if (changeBy === 1) {
    console.log('done');
    return;
  }
  console.log('start ' + testAmount);
  const proms = new Array(testAmount).fill(undefined);
  Promise.all(proms)
    .then(() => {
      // make this loop not fully blocking
      // give time for garbage collection
      console.log(testAmount + ': OK');
      delay(100).then(() => next(testAmount + changeBy));
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(testAmount + ': ' + e.message);
      delay(100).then(() => next(testAmount - changeBy));
    });
};
next(testAmountStart);
```

The result: an error is thrown when an array with 2097151 elements is passed, but 2097150 elements is OK:

```js
const tryProms = length => {
  const proms = new Array(length).fill(undefined);
  Promise.all(proms)
      .then(() => {
      console.log('ok ' + length);
    }).catch(() => {
      console.log('error ' + length);
    });
};
tryProms(2097150);
tryProms(2097151);
```

So, 2097150 is the limit. It likely has something to do with the fact that 2097151 is 0x1FFFFF.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you getting the exact same error as the OP? "RangeError"

Comment: Yes, that's the error, I added a log for the error message